# How do I run different scenarios in CI on emulator and on actual devices?

Tags: continuous-integration, calabash-android

We're using calabash-android to run cucumber scenarios against our android app.  Some scenarios require a physical device, while others run fine on just the emulator.  How can we configure the build so that scenarios tagged @requires_device run on physical devices but do not run on the emulator?

Comment: what's your CI server? Jenkins?

Comment: Actually we're using Bamboo, but I think the approach is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jenkins as your CI server, below are the steps we do to make Calabash run against real devices:

- Create a slave, which is a local machine
- Connect your device to this slave machine (multiple devices should also work)
- Construct your Jenkins to run a job that execute Calabash on slave machine:
  `ADB_DEVICE_ARG=device_id;calabash-android ...`
  `device_id` can be retrieved from `adb devices` command

Since emulator also has a `device_id`, this approach allows you to choose either emulator or real device(s) to run ALL your tests. To run selective tests on certain devices are more tricky, probably requires you to run separate `calabash-android` commands.